# re-order array according to the each hash value

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like

```
$a = $b = $c = [];
$a['num'] = 10;
$b['num'] = 2;
$c['num'] = 4;

$arr = array($a,$b,$c);
```

then now I want to order array `$arr` by hash `['num']`

result should be `array($b,$c,$a)`

I think I can re-order by for loop, but it looks not cool.

I think python has `list in list` but is it possible in PHP?

Is there any good idea to make this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do solve this problem. Basically you have to compare the elements inside the array.

You can just use [usort function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with your custom comparison function.

```
function compare($a, $b) {
   return $a['num'] - $b['num'];
}

usort($arr,"compare");
```

You can also give an anonymous compare function to it. If you do not plan use your custom compare function again, I recommend you to use anonymous function.

```
usort($arr,function($a, $b){
  return $a['num'] - $b['num'];
});
```

**Do not forget**

`usort` function does not return an array. It just returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on fail and the array that you send as a parameter will sort.

Comment: Thank you `usort` is what I want. It's works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()`.

```
sort($arr);
```

The inner arrays are the same length, and all have the same single key, so `sort()` will compare them based on their contents and `$arr` will be sorted as if it was simply an array of integers.